# How to update latitude and longitude from zipcode to the database using Cron Job in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Create a cron script using job/events to update user location details like city, state, longitude, latitude, etc. using the zip code provided on the registration page.

```php
// app/console/commands/Zipcron.php
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $test = new User()
        $test->latitude = $latitude;
        $test->longitude = $longitude;
        $test->save();
        return $this->info('successfully added');

    } catch (exception $e) {
        return $this->warning('successfully added');
    }
}
```

```php
// app/console/kernel.php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command(Commands\ZipCron::class)->everyMinute()
        ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/scheduler.log'));
}
```

Comment: @romil Lat and Long are pretty specific to a single point, while zip-codes cover a region, have you tried using any external api for this?

Comment: yes i tried google api

Comment: Some zip codes cover multiple cities.

Comment: @romil You already have the detail about the address, state, city, and zip code from that you want to get the Lat and Long right?

Comment: when i enter zipcode it will show city and state. and then i wish to submit. after submission it will run cronjob and update automatically  lat and long in database

Comment: @romil https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro this didn't work for you?

Comment: @DsRaj yes sir right. i want lat and long in databse after submit.

Comment: @AdityaThakur  well sir read docs. it work for me only  when i enter zipcode to the textfield. it will shown me city,state,country

Comment: @romil  Pardon me my friend but which text field you are pointing to?

Comment: in blade form..

Comment: You can use curl or guzzle in your handle method to get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: thank you @AdityaThakur sir. i hope it will work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function handle()
    {      
        $trial = Trial::whereNull('lat')->whereNull('lng')->whereNull('address')->get();
        foreach ($trial as $tr)
        {
            $response = Geocode::make()->address($tr->zipcode);
            if ($response){
                $lat     = $response->latitude();
                $lng     = $response->longitude();  
                $city    = $response->raw()->address_components[1]->long_name;
                $state   = $response->raw()->address_components[2]->long_name;
                $address = $response->formattedAddress();
                echo $response->locationType();   
                DB::table('trial')->where('id', $tr->id)->update(['lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng, 'city' => $city, 'state' => $state, 'address' => $address]);          
            }
        }exit;         
    }
```